# Enable TCP/IP and NamedPipe Protocol of MS SQL Server 2012 + Default port change through code or script

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 express edition.

I do have one requirement where I have to enable "Named Pipes" and "TCP/IP" protocols from SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER.
After enabling above protocols, I have to change default port for "All IP" of TCP/IP Protocol to 1433 (in case it is different).

I can do this manually but I am looking for some C#.NET code or any script which I can incorporate with my Visual Studio Installer or any .NET exe program.

CAN ANYBODY PLEASE LET ME KNOW HOW CAN I AUTOMATE THESE 2 THINGS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PowerShell, which I would recommend, then see these scripts from Martin Bell:

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/martinbell/archive/2012/05/07/Changing-SQL-Server-Port-with-Powershell.aspx

There's also a scrip available on the Technet site:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206997%28v=sql.105%29.aspx